# Can we create an event that isn't field-like?

Tags: c#, events

In C# in Depth, Jon Skeet states that:

> Developers often confuse events and delegate instances, or events and fields declared with delegate types.

After reading his explanation I understand much more, though I'm still confused about what exactly an event is. From the code below, it looks like all an event does is to constrain the access that one class has to delegate fields in another class.

> ... you often don't want code outside a class to be able to arbitrarily change (or call) the handlers for an event... [so] the compiler turns the declaration into both an event with default add/remove implementations and a private field of the same type.

In other words, an event differs from a delegate because of access control. Or is this only for what Jon is calling "field-like events"?

- Is a field-like event different from an event?
- Are events in C# always field-like, or can we also create events that are not field-like?
- What is the difference, if any, between an event and a field-like event?

In other words, does C# have support both for events and for field-like events or is this two ways of saying the same thing?

Code Sample here https://dotnetfiddle.net/7fOwvb

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public delegate void TheDelegate(string message);
public static class Program
{
    public static event TheDelegate TheEvent;
    public static TheDelegate DelInstance;
    public static void Main()
    {
        DelInstance = new TheDelegate(TheMethod);
        DelInstance += TheMethod;
        DelInstance.Invoke("Invoke the delegate.");
        PrintMemberInfo(DelInstance.GetType());

        TheEvent += TheMethod;
        TheEvent += TheMethod;
        TheEvent.Invoke("Invoke the event.");
        PrintMemberInfo(TheEvent.GetType());        

        new AnotherClass();
    }

    // Create a method for a delegate. 
    public static void TheMethod(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public static void PrintMemberInfo(System.Type t)
    {
        foreach (MemberInfo m in t.GetMembers())
        {
            Console.Write(m.Name + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public AnotherClass()
    {
        Program.DelInstance += new TheDelegate(AnotherMethod);
        Program.DelInstance.Invoke("Another class");

        // Error... we can only call += or -+
        // Program.TheEvent.Invoke();
    }

    public void AnotherMethod(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can implement an event with custom accessors (add/remove): [How to: Implement Custom Event Accessors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "field-like"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen A field-like event is the event equivalent of an auto-property, i.e. an event with compiler generated `add`/`remove` accessors.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. You were the one that used the term in your question. I get that you don't know the answer to your question, but do you know what your question is?

Comment: If a "field-like event" is one where the backing field is autogenerated by the compiler, then yes, you can declare events without one, specifying the `add/remove` accessors yourself. See the link that @CodesInChaos posted.

Comment: Maybe this blog post clarifies some of your questions: http://blog.rsuter.com/mimic-singlecast-events-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A field-like event is the event equivalent of an auto-property, i.e. an event with compiler generated `add`/`remove` accessors.

> **Field-like events**
>
> Within the program text of the class or struct that contains the declaration of an event, certain events can be used like fields. To be used in this way, an event must not be abstract or extern, and must not explicitly include event-accessor-declarations. Such an event can be used in any context that permits a field. The field contains a delegate (§15) which refers to the list of event handlers that have been added to the event. If no event handlers have been added, the field contains null.
>
> *(C# 5.0 specification)*

You can implement an event with custom accessors (`add` and `remove`) in C#.

```
event EventHandler IDrawingObject.OnDraw
{
    add
    {
        ...
    }
    remove
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

See [How to: Implement Custom Event Accessors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx).